# How to secure Google Maps Javascript V3 API Key within an Ionic/Cordova App?

Tags: cordova, google-maps-api-3, ionic-framework

I want to be prepared for exceeding Google Maps Javascript V3 API usage limits. After exceeding the limit using API will generate some cost. That's why I can't allow anyone, excluding my app, to use it. What type of key should I use and how to include API in my app?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this plugin:

[Cordova GoogleMaps plugin for iOS and Android](https://github.com/mapsplugin/cordova-plugin-googlemaps)

Reasons why to use it:

1. API key is compiled in app.
2. Faster rendering because of vectors.
3. Lower traffic because of vectors.
4. Unlimited free usage, see here: https://github.com/mapsplugin/cordova-plugin-googlemaps